# AmplifyAuthenticator with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I'm building a React JS app and I'd like to use AWS Amplify's `AmplifyAuthenticator` to easily protect routes I configured using `react-router-dom`. I've used Amplify's `withAuthenticator` in the past, but I want to ensure I have the flexibility to customize auth in the future...hence why I'm using `AmplifyAuthenticator`.

I've wrapped my protected routes in the `<AmplifyAuthenticator>` component and it seems to be working fine, but I wanted to make sure this is a solid approach. My code looks like something this:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AmplifySignOut, AmplifySignIn, AmplifyAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import LandingPage from './components/LandingPage';
import ProtectedPage from './components/ProtectedPage';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage}/>
        <Route path="/LangingPage" component={LangingPage}/>
        <AmplifyAuthenticator>
          <Route path="/protected" component={ProtectedPage}/>
        </AmplifyAuthenticator>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is this an efficient way to go about securing these routes? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

wrap the Route into PrivateRoute:

```js
    // A wrapper for <Route> that redirects to the login
    // screen if you're not yet authenticated.
    function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
      let auth = useAuth();
      return (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={({ location }) =>
            auth.user ? (
              children
            ) : (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: "/login",
                  state: { from: location }
                }}
              />
            )
          }
        />
      );
    }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-redirects-auth-xb8qq?from-embed=&file=/example.js